# how i can show 25 values of pixels in matrix 5x5 of rectangle patch using wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

i need to know how i can read and show values of all pixel inside rectangle patch of matrix 5x5 ( 5 rows , 5 column) like a board in other panel

i do this example just to explain what i need to do :

what i need to show in paneltwo is like this example :

[image]

that the code :

```
import wx
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib

class Window(wx.Frame):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, **kwargs)
        RootPanel(self)

class RootPanel(wx.Panel):


    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        panel_buttons = wx.Panel(self)
        panel_buttons_sizer = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)

        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(parent=self)

        select_button = PickButton(
            panel_buttons,
            "netCDF4 files (nc)|*.nc",
            self.canvas_panel.load_from_file,
            label="Show on this window (nc)",
        )
        toplevel_select_button = TopLevelPickButton(
            panel_buttons,
            "Text files (txt)|*.txt|All files|*.*",
            label="Show on separate window (txt)",
        )
        panel_buttons_sizer.Add(select_button)
        panel_buttons_sizer.Add(toplevel_select_button)
        panel_buttons.SetSizer(panel_buttons_sizer)

        canvas_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.panel_two,1,wx.EXPAND)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel_buttons)
        sizer.Add(canvas_sizer)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

class PickButton(wx.Button):


    def __init__(self, parent, wildcard, func, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.wildcard = wildcard
        self.func = func
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pick_file)

    def pick_file(self, evt):
        style = style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wx.FD_MULTIPLE
        with wx.FileDialog(
            self, "Pick files", wildcard=self.wildcard, style=style
        ) as fileDialog:
            if fileDialog.ShowModal() != wx.ID_CANCEL:
                chosen_file = fileDialog.GetPath()
                self.func(chosen_file)

class TopLevelPickButton(PickButton):


    def __init__(self, parent, wildcard, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, wildcard, self.create_toplevel, **kwargs)

    def create_toplevel(self, file_name):
        """ Ouvre une toplevel et affiche le graphique """
        self.win = TopLevelCanvas(self.Parent)
        self.win.canvas_panel.load_from_file(file_name)
        self.win.Show()

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Panel du graphique matplotlib """
    def __init__(self, parent , size=(200,250)):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(5,5))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.Size = self.canvas.Size
        self.parent = parent

    def load_from_file(self, file_name):

        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        if file_name.endswith(".nc"):
            self._load_nc(file_name)
        else:
            self._load_txt(file_name)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def _load_txt(self, file_name):
        self._load_nc(file_name)

    def _load_nc(self, file_name):

        fic='air.departure.sig995.2012.nc'

        path='D:/data/'


        nc = netCDF4.Dataset(path+fic,'r')
        lons = nc.variables['lon'][:]
        lats = nc.variables['lat'][:]
        air_dep = nc.variables['air_dep'][:,:,:]
        air_dep = air_dep[0,:,:]


        self.axes.imshow(air_dep)

        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        x = y = 1
        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 5,5,edgecolor='r', alpha=1, fill=None, label='Label')
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.axes.plot()
        self.Show()

    def on_press(self, click):
        x1, y1 = click.xdata, click.ydata
        self.parent.panel_two.Update(x1,y1)
        zx1 = x1 - 2.5
        zy1 = y1 - 2.5
        zx2 = x1 + 2.5
        zy2 = y1 + 2.5
        self.rect.set_x(x1 - 2.5) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the X click point
        self.rect.set_y(y1 - 2.5) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the Y click point


        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()



class PanelTwo(wx.Panel): #here when i need to visualize pixel and coordinator cursor
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,size=(300,250))

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RICH2, size=(200,170))

        lbl = wx.StaticText(self,label="Coordinato cursor & Pixel ")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(lbl,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,10)
        sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def Update(self,x1,y1):
        self.text_ctrl.SetValue("Mouse click at;\nX "+str(x1)+"\nY "+str(y1))



class TopLevelCanvas(wx.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        self.zoom_panel = Zoom(parent=self)
        self.Size = self.canvas_panel.Size
        canvas_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.zoom_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(canvas_sizer)
        self.Show()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        win = Window(title="A test dialog", size=(1000, 800))
        win.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

is maybe i need to use something like : `**air_dep[x-5:x+5,y-5:y+5]**` in this line of code :

```
def on_press(self, click):
            x1, y1 = click.xdata, click.ydata
            self.parent.panel_two.Update(x1,y1)
```

how i can show the values like matrix or board in example with all column and rows ?

[image]

thank you

other file netcdf4 : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IT-F7AbIx4bCjMLosjBx4F4UCoIX5DU0 [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IT-F7AbIx4bCjMLosjBx4F4UCoIX5DU0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the 5x5 grid is written into the 2nd panel, you could create a separate panel for them.
The 5x5 grid is a bit hacky, as around the edges the grid can become 3x5 or 5x3 and in the corners it has to become 3x3.

```
import wx
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib

class Window(wx.Frame):
    """ Fenêtre principale de l'application """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, **kwargs)
        RootPanel(self)

class RootPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Panel contenant tous les autres widgets de l'application """

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        panel_buttons = wx.Panel(self)
        panel_buttons_sizer = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)

        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(parent=self)

        select_button = PickButton(
            panel_buttons,
            "netCDF4 files (nc)|*.nc",
            self.canvas_panel.load_from_file,
            label="Show on this window (nc)",
        )
        toplevel_select_button = TopLevelPickButton(
            panel_buttons,
            "Text files (txt)|*.txt|All files|*.*",
            label="Show on separate window (txt)",
        )
        panel_buttons_sizer.Add(select_button)
        panel_buttons_sizer.Add(toplevel_select_button)
        panel_buttons.SetSizer(panel_buttons_sizer)

        canvas_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.panel_two,1,wx.EXPAND)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel_buttons)
        sizer.Add(canvas_sizer)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

class PickButton(wx.Button):
    """ Bouton permettant de choisir un fichier """

    def __init__(self, parent, wildcard, func, **kwargs):
        # func est la méthode à laquelle devra être foruni le fichier sélectionné
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.wildcard = wildcard
        self.func = func
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pick_file)

    def pick_file(self, evt):
        style = style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wx.FD_MULTIPLE
        with wx.FileDialog(
            self, "Pick files", wildcard=self.wildcard, style=style
        ) as fileDialog:
            if fileDialog.ShowModal() != wx.ID_CANCEL:
                chosen_file = fileDialog.GetPath()
                self.func(chosen_file)

class TopLevelPickButton(PickButton):
    """ Permet de choisir un fichier et d'ouvrir une toplevel """

    def __init__(self, parent, wildcard, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, wildcard, self.create_toplevel, **kwargs)

    def create_toplevel(self, file_name):
        """ Ouvre une toplevel et affiche le graphique """
        self.win = TopLevelCanvas(self.Parent)
        self.win.canvas_panel.load_from_file(file_name)
        self.win.Show()

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ Panel du graphique matplotlib """
    def __init__(self, parent , size=(200,250)):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize =(5,3))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.Size = self.canvas.Size
        self.parent = parent

    def load_from_file(self, file_name):
        """
        Méthode effectuant l'intermédiaire pour charger le fichier selon
        son type
        """
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        if file_name.endswith(".nc"):
            self._load_nc(file_name)
        else:
            self._load_txt(file_name)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def _load_txt(self, file_name):
        self._load_nc(file_name)

    def _load_nc(self, file_name):
        """ Simule le chargement et affichage à partir d'un fichier nc """
        fic='air.departure.sig995.2012.nc'

        #path='/home/data/'
        path=''


        nc = netCDF4.Dataset(path+fic,'r')
#        print("model",nc.data_model)
#        print("groups",nc.groups)
#        print("dimensions",nc.dimensions)
#        print("variables",nc.variables)
#        for dimobj in nc.dimensions.values():
#            print(dimobj)
#        for name in nc.ncattrs():
#            print("Global attr", name, "=", getattr(nc,name))

        self.lons = nc.variables['lon'][:]
        self.lats = nc.variables['lat'][:]
        air_dep = nc.variables['air_dep'][:,:,:]
        self.lonl = len(self.lons) -1
        self.latl = len(self.lats) -1

        self.air_dep = air_dep[0,:,:]

        self.axes.imshow(self.air_dep)

        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        x = y = 1
        self.rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 5,5,edgecolor='r', alpha=1, fill=None, label='Label')
        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)

    def float_to_dms(self,f,orientation):
        # convert to seconds
        f = f * 3600
        if f < 0:
            div1 = -3600
            div2 = -1
        else:
            div1 = 3600
            div2 = 1
        #Degrees,minutes,seconds
        d,m = divmod(f,div1)
        m,s = divmod(m*60,div1)
        s, x = divmod(s*60,div1)

        d,x = divmod(d,div2)
        m,x = divmod(m,1)
        s,x = divmod(s,1)

        return (orientation+" "+str(int(d))+"° "+str(int(m)).zfill(2)+"' "+str(int(s)).zfill(2)+'"\n')

    def on_press(self, click):
        x1, y1 = click.xdata, click.ydata
        #Longititude values are 2.5 degrees apart for this data
        try:
            lon = x1*2.5
        except:
            print("Out of bounds - Click again")
            return
        if lon < 180.0:
            Ew = "E"
        else:
            Ew = "W"
            lon = (lon - 360.0) -1
        #Latitude values from 90 to -90 2.5 degrees apart
        #split the y value
        i,f = divmod(y1,1)
        lat = self.lats[int(i)]
        #calculate the fraction of degrees
        if lat > 0 and lat < 87.5:
            lat = lat+(f*2.5)
        elif lat < 0 and lat > -87.5:
            lat = lat-(f*2.5)
        if lat < 0.0:
            Ns= "S"
        else:
            Ns = "N"
        #Convert to ° ' "
        lon_dms = self.float_to_dms(lon,Ew)
        lat_dms = self.float_to_dms(lat,Ns)

        #air_dep seems the wrong way round but what do I know
        #The way below gives values that seem correct
        air = self.air_dep[int(y1),int(x1)]
        air_rect =[]
        x = int(x1)
        y = int(y1)
        # Build valid values for rectangle
        # to cater for values beyond the edge of the map
        if x-1 < 0: x2 = 0
        else: x2 = x-2
        if x+2 > self.lonl: x3 = self.lonl+1
        else: x3 = x+3
        if y-2 < 0:
            pass
        else:
            air_rect.append(self.air_dep[y-2,x2:x3])
        if y-1 < 0:
            pass
        else:
            air_rect.append(self.air_dep[y-1,x2:x3])
        air_rect.append(self.air_dep[y,x2:x3])
        if y+1 > self.latl:
            pass
        else:
            air_rect.append(self.air_dep[y+1,x2:x3])
        if y+2 > self.latl:
            pass
        else:
            air_rect.append(self.air_dep[y+2,x2:x3])

        self.parent.panel_two.Update(x1,y1,lon,lat,air,lon_dms,lat_dms,Ns,Ew,air_rect)
        zx1 = x1 - 2.5
        zy1 = y1 - 2.5
        zx2 = x1 + 2.5
        zy2 = y1 + 2.5
        self.rect.set_x(x1 - 2.5) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the X click point
        self.rect.set_y(y1 - 2.5) #Move the rectangle and centre it on the Y click point
        self.axes.plot()
        self.canvas.draw()



class PanelTwo(wx.Panel): #here when i need to visualize pixel and coordinator cursor
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,size=(300,250))

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RICH2, size=(300,300))

        lbl = wx.StaticText(self,label="Coordinato cursor & Pixel ")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(lbl,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,10)
        sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def Update(self,x1,y1,lon,lat,air,lon_dms,lat_dms,Ns,Ew,air_rect):
        update_str = "Mouse click at;\nX "+str(x1)+"\nLon "+Ew+" "+str(lon)+"\n"+lon_dms+"\nY "+str(y1)+"\nLat "+Ns+" "+str(lat)+"\n"+lat_dms+"\nAir Value at point "+str(air)+"\n"
        self.text_ctrl.SetValue(update_str)
        self.text_ctrl.write("Surrounding values\n")
        #Table of surrounding temperatures
        for i in range(len(air_rect)):
            s = ""
            line = air_rect[i]
            for i2 in line:
                s+="{:5.1f}".format(i2)+"  "
            self.text_ctrl.write(s+"\n")

class TopLevelCanvas(wx.Frame):
    """ Fenêtre affichant uniquement un graph matplotlib """

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.canvas_panel = CanvasPanel(self)
        self.zoom_panel = Zoom(parent=self)
        self.Size = self.canvas_panel.Size
        canvas_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.canvas_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        canvas_sizer.Add(self.zoom_panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(canvas_sizer)
        self.Show()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        win = Window(title="A test dialog", size=(1000, 800))
        win.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: oh thank you but i have question in this line : `if x-1 < 0: x2 = 0
        else: x2 = x-2
        if x+2 > self.lonl: x3 = self.lonl+1
        else: x3 = x+3
        if y-2 < 0:
            pass
        else:
            air_rect.append(self.air_dep[y-2,x2:x3])
        if y-1 < 0:
            pass
        else:
            air_rect.append(self.air_dep[y-1,x2:x3])...` i don't understand why are you used lat and lon cause i have other file netcdf4 without value of lat and lon and i don't need it so with which I can replace the  lat and lon one in these lines of code ? thank you

Comment: is there a way to not use lat and lon in these lines of the code? to use just x and y ? thank you

Comment: I can only run with the data I have access to, which contains latitude, longitude and temperatures `air.departure.sig995.2012.nc`. I have no idea what this `other` file is or contains.

Comment: the other file have  GeosCoordinateSystem( X,Y) and not lat & lon, i will edit my question to add other file , but my question if i can use  GeosCoordinateSystem ( X,Y) in these lines of code or need to convert there to lat&lon ? thank you